# I ran a command with `-->` in bash. What does it do?

Tags: bash, zsh

I was hoping this would just become a string, it was meant to be an arrow. But, the shell ate the command. I'd like to know what `echo A --> B` does when you run it in bash or zsh, what does the shell actually do?

Comment: if you meant to output `-->` literally use quotes or escape the `>` token. `echo A --\> B`

Comment: A command of just `-->` would give an error for the missing filename on the redirection

Answer (score 6):

It produces a file in the current working directory named `B` that just contains in it the content

```
A --
```

So, the `>` is just performing stdout redirection to the file B here. The space not being present before the `>` is irrelevant.

If you meant to write an arrow as text you should put it in quotes so the shell doesn't try to parse it:

```
echo 'A --> B'
```